# SQL Server sub partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, database-administration

Same concept I want to use SQL Server.

This code is working fine in Oracle server. But I tried it in SQL Server, and I'm not able to get it.

```
CREATE TABLE MENT_OVD
 PARTITION BY RANGE  (OV_LENGTH) SUBPARTITION BY LIST (OV_TYPE)

  (     PARTITION OVD_P0 VALUES LESS THAN (2)
            ( SUBPARTITION OVD_S0 VALUES ('N'),
            SUBPARTITION OVD_S1 VALUES ('A'),
            SUBPARTITION OVD_S2 VALUES (DEFAULT)
            ),
        PARTITION OVD_P1 VALUES LESS THAN (3)
            ( SUBPARTITION OVD_S0 VALUES ('N'),
            SUBPARTITION OVD_S1 VALUES ('A'),
            SUBPARTITION OVD_S2 VALUES (DEFAULT)
            ),
        PARTITION OVD_P2 VALUES LESS THAN (4)
            ( SUBPARTITION OVD_S3 VALUES ('N'),
            SUBPARTITION OVD_S4 VALUES ('A'),
            SUBPARTITION OVD_S5 VALUES (DEFAULT)
            ),  
        PARTITION OVD_P3 VALUES LESS THAN (5)
            ( SUBPARTITION OVD_S6 VALUES ('N'),
            SUBPARTITION OVD_S7 VALUES ('A'),
            SUBPARTITION OVD_S8 VALUES (DEFAULT)
            ),
        PARTITION OVD_P4 VALUES LESS THAN (6)
            ( SUBPARTITION OVD_S9 VALUES ('N'),
            SUBPARTITION OVD_S10 VALUES ('A'),
            SUBPARTITION OVD_S11 VALUES (DEFAULT)
            ),
        PARTITION OVD_P5 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
        (SUBPARTITION OVD_S12 VALUES (DEFAULT)
        )
    )
```

Comment: What was your SQL Server attempt? Why didn't it work? We can't debug code we can't see. :)

Comment: SQL Server only allows table partitioning on a single column. Not knowing anything about Oracle partitioning and your reason for partitioning in the first place, I can't suggest alternatives.

Comment: I have 5000000 data in my table. If i want to fetch the data from my table it's taking more time.So i have planed for partition and sub partition concept.

Oracle is working fine but how to do in sql server.......

Comment: If any one is there please help me ..........

How to do partition in sql server

Comment: In SQL, partitioning isn't particularly a performance feature but a data management one. For instance, if you have a "sliding window" scenario (i.e. "keep 90d worth"), it's easier/less impactful to drop old partitions than to do a delete of the data. Also, if you have very large table, partitioning can help with partition maintenance (as you're only doing rebuilds/reorgs on a smaller data set). But, if you want to partition on an aggregate key, you can add a computed column to your table that is the concatenation of the columns and partition on that.